# Loggin in doesn't do anything in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-volley

I'm using **Android Volley** to make my login authentication works. However, when clicking the login button it doesn't work. I also added a

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in the **AndroidManifest.xml**, I checked if the server is responding, and if there is no errors with **Postman** (Chrome Extension). I've added a "***displayMessage***" on **onClick** event (on XML)

This is my **Authentication.java** (this handles the GUI, and I make request to LoginRequest to process my login)

```
...
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
...

public void displayMessage(View v){
        TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        EditText usernameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        EditText passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

        // Fetch Username and Password
        final String strUsername = usernameField.getText().toString();
        String strPassword = passwordField.getText().toString();

        // Fetch Length of Strings
        int intUsername = usernameField.getText().length();
        int intPassword = passwordField.getText().length();

        if(strUsername.matches("")){
            messageText.setText("Please put a valid username!");

        } else if(intUsername < 3){
            messageText.setText("Username length is not enough!");

        } else if(intUsername > 16){
            messageText.setText("Username length exceeded to maximum value!");

        } else if(strPassword.matches("")) {
            messageText.setText("Please put a valid password!");

        } else if(intPassword < 6){
            messageText.setText("Password length is not enough!");

        } else if(intPassword > 32){
            messageText.setText("Password length exceeded to maximum value!");

        } else {
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        String requestMessage = jsonResponse.getString("message");
                        if (success){
                            String UUID = jsonResponse.getString("unique_user_id");
                            String last_login = jsonResponse.getString("last_login");
                            String registration_date = jsonResponse.getString("registration_date");


                            Intent i = new Intent(Authentication.this, Mainpage.class);
                            i.putExtra("username", strUsername);
                            i.putExtra("UUID", UUID);
                            i.putExtra("last_login", last_login);
                            i.putExtra("registration_date", registration_date);
                            startActivity(i);
                        } else {
                            TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                            messageText.setText(requestMessage);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(strUsername, strPassword, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    }
```

This is my **LoginRequest.java** (this handles the request from Authentication.java)

```
...
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
...

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://blocktest.pe.hu/bta-api/api/v1/request.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String>getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code working fine on my part. I skipped the validation though. You might want to double check whether the request is actually being made. I'm using `'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`. You might also need to add ErrorListener so you will be notified in case something went wrong when the request is being made.

Comment: I've checked m POST request with **Postman** and it works. I don't know how to add an ErrorListener cause i'm a newbie on Android Development tho.

Comment: @AhmadFadli Any suggestions? I've checked the volley if it is getting compiled and it is.

Comment: You can provide the error listener in the 4th parameter of `super()` in LoginReequest constructor.

Comment: What should I put tho?